# Regex that matches a newline (\n) in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

OK, this one is driving me nuts....
I have a string that is formed thus:

```
var newContent = string.Format("({0})\n{1}", stripped_content, reply)
```

newContent will display like:
    (old text)
    new text

I need a regular expression that strips away the text between parentheses with the parenthesis included AND the newline character.

The best I can come up with is:

```
const string  regex = @"^(\(.*\)\s)?(?<capture>.*)";
var match= Regex.Match(original_content, regex);
var stripped_content = match.Groups["capture"].Value;
```

This works, but I want specifically to match the newline (`\n`), not any whitespace (`\s`)
Replacing `\s` with `\n` `\\n` or `\\\n` does NOT work.

Please help me hold on to my sanity!

EDIT: an example:

```
public string Reply(string old,string neww)
        {
            const string  regex = @"^(\(.*\)\s)?(?<capture>.*)";
            var match= Regex.Match(old, regex);
            var stripped_content = match.Groups["capture"].Value;
            var result= string.Format("({0})\n{1}", stripped_content, neww);
            return result;
        }

Reply("(messageOne)\nmessageTwo","messageThree") returns :
(messageTwo)
messageThree
```

Comment: Could you post a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem? I'm finding it hard to piece together at the moment.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

If you specify RegexOptions.Multiline then you can use `^` and `$` to match the start and end of a line, respectively.

If you don't wish to use this option, remember that a new line may be any one of the following: `\n`, `\r`, `\r\n`, so instead of looking only for `\n`, you should perhaps use something like: `[\n\r]+`, or more exactly: `(\n|\r|\r\n)`.

Comment: Don't forget that alternation isn't greedy; if you apply your regex to `"\r\n"` it will only match `"\r"`.  I would use `(\n|\r\n?)` or maybe `(\r\n?|\n)` instead.

Comment: I could not get it to work with the Multiline option.
(\n|\r|\r\n) did the trick. It surfaced that in this particular case \r\n was necessary to get a match, even though I inserted only \n in the string to be matched.

Comment: @AlanMoore thanks for that.  I was confused why `\r\n` was matching twice.

Answer (score 30):

Actually it works but with opposite option i.e.

```cs
 RegexOptions.Singleline
```

Comment: nice! that fixed it for me! somehow, line endings werent ignored using the multiline option. but with single line did it! +1

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, multi-line input is processed just fine in `Singleline` mode ... but the behavior differs and sometimes the `Singleline` behavior is what you need! i knew my input was multi-line, so i without really thinking about it set the `Multiline` option ... but in this case `.` (dot) doesn't match the newline char(s) which was what i really wanted. Setting to `Singleline` fixed this issue. `$` in that cases matches the end of the input string which is also convenient. So lesson learned: multi-line input does not always mean the `Multiline` option should be used!

Comment: I don't know whether this is what the OP wanted or not but it was what I wanted ! That is to search the text for my regex and, effectively, ignore line feeds. Thanks.

Comment: SingleLine is not the opposite of MultiLine. They are different concepts with unfortunate names and can be used together.

Comment: You're a genius.

Answer (score 5):

You are probably going to have a \r before your \n.  Try replacing the \s with (\r\n).

Answer (score 5):

Counter-intuitive as it is, you can use both `Multiline` and `Singleline` option.

```
Regex.Match(input, @"(.+)^(.*)", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

First capturing group will contain first line (including  `\r` and `\n`) and second group will have second line.

#### Why:

First of all `RegexOptions` enum is [flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute) so it can be combined with bitwise operators, then

- `Multiline`:

> `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of each line (instead of the beginning and end of the input string).

- `Singleline`:

> The period (`.`) matches every character (instead of every character except `\n`)

[see docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options)

Answer (score 3):

Think I may be a bit late to the party, but still hope this helps.

I needed to get multiple tokens between two hash signs.

Example i/p:

## token1 ##
## token2 ##
## token3_a
token3_b
token3_c ##

This seemed to work in my case:

`var matches = Regex.Matches (mytext, "##(.*?)##", RegexOptions.Singleline);`

Of course, you may want to replace the double hash signs at both ends with your own chars.

HTH.