# Regex end-of-line anchor doesn't always work

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm working on an ASP .NET (C#) project that makes use of regular expressions and I'm having trouble with the end-of-line anchors! I'm looking for some text and I want to make sure it only occurs at the end of a string.

Here's some sample input that demonstrates my problem. For this case I'm trying to match the word "text" at the end.

> This text is my sample text

And here are the expressions I've tried (with the IgnoreCase option):

```
text\z
text\Z
text$
```

Now here's the crazy part. None of these regular expressions work on my system (Windows 8 Pro 64-bit, VS2010, .NET 4.0). I've debugged in my project and I've also tried the "Regex Tester" app from the Windows 8 store. It will not match!

However, if I use an online regex tester, for example Derek Slager's at [his blog post](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx) which runs on .NET, or this Silverlight one at http://regexhero.net/tester/, using the exact same patterns and inputs, it matches the final instance of "text" with no problem.

I'm confused. I really need reliable end-of-string matching and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT: Apparently I can't used compiled regex's. Here's an example using the data the project actually runs on:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = "http://192.168.0.113/MidlandGIS/rest/services/Osceola_Assessor_Data/MapServer/?f=pjson";
        string pattern = @"mapserver/\?f=(json|pjson)$";

        Regex myRegex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase & RegexOptions.Compiled);
        Console.Write("Trying compiled regex: ");
        if (myRegex.IsMatch(url))
            Console.WriteLine("Match");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("No match.");

        myRegex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        Console.Write("Trying non-compiled regex: ");
        if (myRegex.IsMatch(url))
            Console.WriteLine("Match");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("No match.");

        Console.Write("Trying inline regex: ");
        if (Regex.IsMatch(url, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            Console.WriteLine("Match");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("No match");

        Console.Write("Press any key to terminate.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

outputs

> Trying compiled regex: No match
>
> Trying non-compiled regex: Match
>
> Trying inline regex: Match
>
> Press any key to terminate.

Edit again: OK I'm a complete idiot. I was using bitwise AND when I should be using bitwise OR to combine the regex options. Compiled regex's work just fine now.

Comment: Try `IgnoreCase | Multiline`

Comment: Please show us the code that uses the regex.

Comment: I think we need to see exactly what code you have - I.e. can you write a one-liner that tries to match your string against the pattern?

Comment: Typing `?System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch("This text is my sample text","text$")` <enter> into the immediate window returns `true`.

Comment: OK I'm a complete idiot. I was using bitwise AND when I should be using bitwise OR to combine the regex options. Compiled regex's work just fine now.

Comment: @TJMott shouldn't that be `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled`?

Comment: Ah okay, a second too late :D

Comment: Those simple mistakes are the hardest to find, sometimes.

Answer (score 7):

Try to use this:

```
 (\n|\r|\r\n)
```

For more info see: [Regex that matches a newline (\n) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175053/regex-that-matches-a-newline-n-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quote straight from one of the best regex sources out there.

> The Regex allows an optional second parameter of type RegexOptions.
>   You could specify RegexOptions.IgnoreCase as the final parameter to
>   make the regex case insensitive. Other options are
>   RegexOptions.Singleline which causes the dot to match newlines and
>   **RegexOptions.Multiline which causes the caret and dollar to match at
>   embedded newlines in the subject string**.

You may just need to set that option to get what you want. You can check [the rest of the page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html) for more information on .net and regex.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not that easy, I don't think. `^abc$` doesn't match `abc\r\nstuff` for some reason, even with multiline turned on. It doesn't even match `abc`. Check [this .NET based tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5eabc%24&i=+abc%0d%0aabc%0d%0a&o=m). Remove the `$`, and [profit](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5eabc&i=abc%0d%0aspammity+spam%0d%0aabc%0d%0amore+spam&o=m). I'm seeing that in my C# code too. Looks like `$` [doesn't respect the multiline option](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5eabc%24&i=+abc%0d%0aabc%0d%0aabc&o=m).

Comment: That's because [.NET only recognizes `\n` as a newline character, being a Windows based language](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html#linebreak). The tester you are linking to uses `\r\n` for it's newlines as seen in the url params (%0D%0A).