# Regex for new line in string (str) in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have exhausted my search and need asisstance.  I am new to regex and have managed to pull words from a multi lined string, however not a whole line.
I have text pulled into string but I cannot find out to grab the next line.

Example string has multiple lines (string multipleLines):

```
 Authentication information
 User information:
 domai n\username
 Paris
```

I need to grab the text "domain\username" after the line "User iformation."

I have tried many combinations of regex and cannot get it to work.  Example:

```
 string topLine = "Authentication information";  
 label.Text = Regex.Match(multipleLines, topLine + "(.*)").Groups[1].Value;
```

I also tried using: topLine + "\n"
What should I add to look at the entire next line after getting the line for Authentication information?

Comment: Use String.Split to split MultipleLines into a string array, then check each item in the array for what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, however, I do not know how to accomplish this.  I owuld need to know the commands or examples.  I have been workign on this for a week and cannot find th answer on my own.

Answer (score 1):

Your objective with *Regular Expressions* can be found here at this thread [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175053/regex-that-matches-a-newline-n-in-c-sharp).  You would want to implement the `RegexOptions.Multiline` so you can make usage of the `^` and `$` to match the Start and End of a line.

- `^`: Depending on whether the MultiLine option is set, matches the position before the first character in a line, or the first character in the string.
- `$`: Depending on whether the MultiLine option is set, matches the position after the last character in a line, or the last character in the string.

Those would be the easiest way to accomplish your task.

---

**Update:**

An example would be something like this.

```
const string account = @"Authentication information:" + "\n"
     + "User Information: " + "\n"
     + "Domain Username: "
     + " \n" + "\\Paris";

MatchCollection match = Regex.Matches(account, ^\\.*$, RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

That will retrieve the line with the `\\` and all that proceed it on that line.  That is an example, hopefully that points you in the correct direction.

Comment: I have read that example and I cannot find how it can work. Can someone provide an example for me using my example?

Comment: @AskQuestion Did you write a loop at the end of Expression; so it recursively populates the match for you?

Answer (score 0):

Though RegEx would accomplish what you want, this might be simpler and far less overhead. Using this code depends on the kind of input you'll be receiving. For your example, this will work:

```
string domainUsername = inputString.Split('\n').Where(z => z.ToLower().Contains(@"\")).FirstOrDefault();
if (domainUsername != null) {
    Console.WriteLine(domainUsername); // Should spit out the appropriate line.
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Domain and username not found!"); // Line not found
}
```

Comment: Thank you, howver, I have a multi-line string and wish to get the next line after a string of text.  I am not looking to parse the entire string entry as there are more "\" slashes.