# Why isn't my regex matching in VB.net

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm not sure why this regex isn't matching. Maybe you can spot the error.

```
Dim rx2 As New Regex(">+ Client (.+) <+\n([^>]*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
If rx2.IsMatch(fiContents) Then
    Debug.Print("Matched")
End If
```

fiContents:

```
============ Computer 200xx; User Comp\nnnn; Oct, 07 2015 10:33 AM
Print list: 9462
>>>>> Client 9462 <<<<<
Had a program exception; please check the error log
```

I want to match >>>>> Client 9462 <<<<< capturing the number and also everything after that up to another client number. So my first capture is "9462" and the second is "Had a program exception; please check the error log".

It works perfectly in [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/mT9lE0/1) using JavaScript setting. What's different about VB.net that it isn't matching?

Comment: What's `(.+)` for ? What pattern are you trying to match ? Give some valid and invalid examples.

Comment: @noob the `(.+)` matches the client number. The fiContents shown above show the string I'm matching.

Comment: For numbers you should use ([0-9])* or (\d)*. I will prefer using first one.

Comment: @noob That's irrelevant to the question. The client number could be any character. The > and < delimit the client number quite clearly.

Comment: Also try using `*` outside the group like this `>+ Client (.+) <+\n([^>])*`.

Comment: @noob That doesn't make it match. (tried it)

Comment: My suspicion goes to use of `\n` in VB.NET.

Comment: Found an [answer here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175053/regex-that-matches-a-newline-n-in-c-sharp) Which agrees with my suspicion.

Comment: @noob Beautiful! That's the answer. You can post it as such. Thanks so much.

Comment: I cannot post it as an answer. It will be plagiarism. I am glad it helped you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104697/discussion-between-noob-and-d-bester).

Comment: Ended up using `>+ Client (.+) <+\r?\n?([^>]` thanks to Noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noob pointed out that `/n` might be a problem. Looking into it I realized that the string included a CR and LF (when debug.Print > pasting into Regex101.com it removed the CR). Since the regex was looking only for LF it didn't match. So I fixed it by using `>+ Client (.+) <+\r?\n?([^>]` as the regex. That works perfectly.

Comment: That is why **you cannot rely on [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) to test .NET regex**. Use [regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester) where linebreaks are always CRLF.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the link. But what if my string really only has LF? That is not uncommon. For me personally the problem was my unsupported assumption that `\n` would include `\r\n` which is not true. Lesson learned.

Comment: If you are unsure how many and what type your linebreak is, just replace `\n`  with `[\r\n]+`.