# Regex for extracting certain part to be match

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, itext

I'm trying to extract certain data from a string with regex. The string looks like this:

> some description points goes here
>
> Experience
>
> Company Name
>
> 1 year 4 months
>
> software Developer
>
> April 2020 - Present (1 year 1 month)
>
> City Name, State Name, country Name
>
> some description points goes here

```cs
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();    
string pdfData = string.Empty, pdfData2 = string.Empty;

Regex re = new Regex(regexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path))
{
    for (int pageNo = 1; pageNo <= reader.NumberOfPages; pageNo++)
    {
        ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
        pdfData += PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, pageNo, strategy);
        Match match = re.Match(pdfData);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            pdfData2 += match.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to extract the company name, duration (1 year 4 months), and designation (Software Developer), where this regex pattern matches (April 2020 - Present (1 year 1 month)). When this pattern matches, I want to get the three lines before this pattern.

I have tried `string regex Pattern = @"[ADFJMNOS][a-z]{2,8}\s[12][0-9]{3}\b";`. This gets me only **April 2020**.

Comment: You pattern does not contain anything that could match lines before, so "April 2020" seems to be the correct match. What have you tried to get the three lines before this pattern?

Comment: @ChristophLütjen I don't know how to create such regex pattern that get me those three lines before the pattern

Comment: Not related to your regex question per se, but keep in mind that `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` extracts the content in the order it appears in the PDF content stream, which is not necessarily the same as the order it appears on the page.

Comment: So you're asking "How to include line breaks in my regex"? This one should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175053/regex-that-matches-a-newline-n-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to get three lines before this pattern.
>
> I have tried `string regex Pattern = @"[ADFJMNOS][a-z]{2,8}\s[12][0-9]{3}\b";`

If you insert `((.*\n){3})` at the start of your pattern string, `match.Groups[1]` will contain the desired *three lines before this pattern*.

Comment: Thanks Armali It solves my problem , but this ragex pattern is not working on January 2020 Why?

Comment: It is working on January 2020 - so there seems to be something else, perhaps two spaces between month and year? - you can easily test it online, e.g. here: https://regex101.com/

Comment: @Dev.Sab - We should be able to see the reason if you add the _not working_ line to the question post.