# Regex in .net seems to not work correctly

Tags: c#, .net, regex, replace

I want strip html from string with regular expression and while this regex works everywhere it does not work in .net I don't understand why.

```cs
using System;
                        
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var text = "FOO <span style=\"mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt;\nmso-fareast-language:EN-US\"> BAR";
        var res = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(text, "<.*?>", "");
        Console.WriteLine(res);
    }
}
```

Comment: See [Regex that matches a newline (\n) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175053/regex-that-matches-a-newline-n-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the correct Regex option:

```
var res = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(text, "<.*?>", "", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

The reason you need this is because you have a newline (`\n`) in your HTML. `Singleline` will ensure that `.` even matches newline characters.

Docs blurb:

> Specifies single-line mode. Changes the meaning of the dot (.) so it matches every character (instead of every character except \n). For more information, see the "Single-line Mode" section in the [Regular Expression Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options) article.

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=net-6.0)

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/DGVQ16560)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(text, "<[^>]*>", "");
```

This will strip the html of your string.